# Tear down between multiple test cases for Test::More in Perl

Tags: perl, unit-testing, tdd

I've got a perl subroutine that should return the number of primes between `a` and `b` inclusive. I've got a test for this in `testSub.t`:

```
 
my $arrayref = MyPackage::generatePrimes(1,2);

my @array = @$arrayref;
is ( scalar(@array), 1, "One primes between (1,2)");
```

I need to rerun `MyPackage::generatePrimes` with a few other inputs (`1..3`, `10..15` etc). I could just do:

```
my $arrayref;
my @array;

# Test between (1,2)
$arrayref = MyPackage::generatePrimes(1,2); 
@array = @$arrayref;
is ( scalar(@array), 1, "One primes between (1,2)");

# Test between (1,3)
$arrayref = MyPackage::generatePrimes(1,3);
@array = @$arrayref;
is ( scalar(@array), 2, "Two primes between (1,3)");
```

which works fine, in this case. If I've got slightly more complex routines and tests, though, this doesn't seem very *clean* in that there could be leakage between the tests when I re-use the variables.

What's the correct ("clean") method to add a second test?  Is there a clean way to do this in `testSub.t` (tear-down `arrayref` and other variables that were generated by the above test before I test the subroutine again), or do I just write another test in `testSub2.t`?

Comment: In general, test the thing you want to test for directly. Don't derive it. In the above, what if your funtion returns a null or an invalid pointer? You assignment to @array will fail and not be caught by test.

Comment: @starbolin Could you give a directly-tested example? My attempts to get the scalar length of the array returned by  `MyPackage::generatePrimes(1,2)` in one line fail.

Comment: $ perl -e '$array_ref=["foo","bar","glarch"];print $#{$array_ref}'

Comment: Isn't there only one prime in (1 .. 2), and two in (1 .. 3)?

Comment: @JimDavis Yes. [`1` isn't prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number). The tests used here got replaced when I added another test to ensure `1` wasn't returned as part of the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply wrap your testing code in a subroutine.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict ;
use warnings ;
use Test::More ;
use MyPackage ;

#             from, to, primes
my @tests = ( [ 1 , 2 , 2 ] ,
              [ 1 , 3 , 3 ] ) ;
# Just add new tests as needed

plan tests => @tests ;

foreach my $test ( @tests ) {
  do_the_test( $test ) ;
}

sub do_the_test {
  my @args = @{ $_[0] } ;

  my @array = @{ MyPackage::generatePrimes( @args[0..1] ) } ;
  is( scalar @array , $args[2] ,
      sprintf( "Primes between (%d,%d): %d" , @args ) ) ;
}
```

Since each test is inside the subroutine the tests are seperate from each other.
If you have more arguments you have to pass to your subroutine, you should think about passing the arguments in a hash.

Comment: In the `foreach` loop, you'd need to have `do_the_test( @$test )` - otherwise you pass the reference to the array, not the array, which fails the subroutine (I think - I'm pretty new to perl). That's a really neat solution, though - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't copy to  another array.

<strike>is(@#{$arrayref}+1,2)</strike>

```
is($#{$arrayref}+1,2)
```

Or,wrap your allocations in a do block.

```
do {
    my @array = @( my_function());
    is( scalar( @array),2 );
}
```

The allocation of @array is scoped within the block.